# Accessing Elements in 2-Dimensional Array Elm

Tags: elm

How do I get at certain elements in this array using Array.get?

First I have a 2D List:

```
node = [['X',' ',' '],['O','O',' '],['X',' ',' ']]
-- so node is a [['X','X',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']] : List (List Char)
```

I convert it to a 2D array so I get:

```
Array.fromList [Array.fromList ['X','X',' '],Array.fromList [' ',' ',' '],Array.fromList [' ',' ',' ']] : Array.Array (Array.Array Char)
```

*although side note: why did the repl give me that instead of just reporting it as [['X','X',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']] : Array.Array (Array.Array Char) ?  Just wondered, thought that was odd.*

so now node's a 2D array instead of a list.

Now what if I want to access the value at say position `[0][1]` in the 2D array, so the second `'X'` in the first row (so that's index 1) 2D array, how would I do that with `get`?

Once I figure out how to do this then I will need to figure out how to update that position, for example change an X to an O or change an empty position to an X or O

Is it me or just trying to work with 2D Lists or 2D arrays in elm is just a huge PITA?

Comment: It might be worth to think about your data model. Maybe Elm won't feel so unruly if you'd use a list of coordinates instead of a 2D Array. That's what works best for Game Of Life in my opinion. It seems like your modelling Tic Tac Toe. Maybe it would be even easier to just use a list with nine values. I've had the best results modelling a Sudoku board as an Array of length 81.

Comment: I actually ended up doing just that..using a dictionary now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it me or just trying to work with 2D Lists or 2D arrays in elm is just a huge PITA?

Linked list is a more common structure in functional languages and most of the reasoning about algorithms is based on them, that's why working with classic arrays instead can be tedious sometimes (the option is to review the structure of your application and make lists fit into this structure).

Regarding the question, imagine you have such a function:

```
arrayNode : Array.Array (Array.Array Char)
arrayNode = Array.fromList [Array.fromList ['X','X',' '],Array.fromList [' ',' ',' '],Array.fromList [' ',' ',' ']]
```

To get a `0` row in this array [Array.get](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Array#get) function can be used:

```
Array.get 0 arrayNode
```

As far as I understand, the difficulty is that `Maybe (Array.Array Char)` type is returned, so we can't use `Array.get` one more time straight away.

We could use `case` expression and check whether the result is `Just (Array.Array Char)` or `Nothing`, but actually there's [Maybe.andThen](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Maybe#andThen) function, which can simplify the code:

```
Array.get 0 arrayNode |> Maybe.andThen (Array.get 1)
```

The result is `Just 'X'`, as expected

Comment: Appreciate the explanation as I am new to ML and Elm.  Will try it out in a few minutes